# Use NSDictionary as other NSDictionary's key

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to achieve the following structure:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{} mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *key1 = @{@"id_format": @(1), @"date": @"2014-08-01"};
NSDictionary *key2 = @{@"id_format": @(2), @"date": @"2014-08-02"};

// This runs perfect and can be checked in llvm debugger
// data1 & data2 are NSArray that contain several NSDictionary
[dict setObject:data1 forKey:key1];
[dict setObject:data2 forKey:key2];

// Later, if i try to access dict using another key, returns empty NSArray
NSDictionary *testKey = @{@"id_format": @(1), @"date": @"2014-08-01"}; // Note it's equal to "key1"

for(NSDictionary *dictData in dict[testKey]){
// dictData is empty NSArray
}

// OR

for(NSDictionary *dictData in [dict objectForKey:testKey]){
// dictData is empty NSArray
}
```

So the question is if is there possible to use NSDictionary as key, or not.

Comment: I think that `data1` and `data2` are `nil`, because I have tested your code and it works just fine.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `key1` and `testKey` are equal?

Comment: They have the same components, but not the same object

Comment: It seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object can be used as a key if it conforms to `NSCopying`, and should implement `hash` and `isEqual:` to compare by value rather than by identity.

Dictionaries follow the array convention of returning `[self count]` for `hash`. So it's a pretty bad hash but it's technically valid. It means your outer dictionary will end up doing what is effectively a linear search but it'll work.

Dictionaries implement and correctly respond to `isEqual:`. They also implement `NSCopying`.

Therefore you can use a dictionary as a dictionary key.

Comment: So they "can" be used, but the outcome is not the desired. Thanks

Comment: The outcome is exactly as desired in terms of the interface. Just don't think you're getting a hashmap if all your keys are dictionaries with the same number of items.